# no suitable method found for setPreferredSize(int,int)

Tags: java

So im trying to create my first window app and a program shows the following error in the console:

> No suitable method found for setPreferredSize(int,int)

How can i fix it?

Comment: Difficult to say given you haven't shown any code. You need to make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: we need to see the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setPreferredSize does not accept two ints as paramaters, it only accepts a Dimension object. You will need to instantiate a Dimension object with the size you want and then pass that in. Something like:

```
Dimension frameSize = new Dimension(X, Y);
```

and then  do

```
setPreferredSize(frameSize);
```

Comment: it works, thanks :)

Comment: cool, could you accept the answer if possible? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`setPreferredSize` not have a constructor which take two int there are one which take `Dimension`, so Instead of `setPreferredSize(int, int)` you can use this:

```
component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
```

Comment: I doubt OP is literally calling `setPreferredSize(int, int)`.

Comment: This error mean that the OP use `.setPreferredSize(1,5);` and there are no constructor which take two int @shmosel i'm wrong?

Comment: Probably not...

Comment: mmm, what is that mean Probably not @shmosel :) ?

Comment: You're probably not wrong. I just misunderstood you.

Comment: ah ok thank you @shmosel